# How close can the solutions of $x^\pi = 1$ get to $-1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I believe the solutions to $x^\pi = 1$ are $e^{2ni}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if this is true, the arc distance from any solution and $-1$ has to have a limit, otherwise $(-1)^\pi$ would equal $1$.

So, is my understanding of this wrong, or is there actually a limit to how close the solutions can get to $-1$?

Comment: How do you define $x^\pi$ for an arbitrary $x\in\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence $\lbrace e^{in} \mid n \in \mathbb N \rbrace$ is in fact dense in the circle $\mathbb S^1$. So for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that
$$|e^{in} - i| < \varepsilon. $$
Thus, $e^{2in}$ and $-1$ can be arbitrarly close (the square function is continuous on $\mathbb C$). But this does not contradict the fact that $e^{in\pi^2} \neq 1$. That is because the function
$$z \mapsto z^{\pi} $$

is kind of tricky to define on $\mathbb C$. In fact, it cannot be defined on the whole complex plain (if you want it to be continuous at least). Usually it is defined on $\mathbb C \backslash \mathbb R^-$ by $z^{\pi} = e^{\pi \log(z)}$ (or $z^{\pi} = |z| e^{i \pi\arg(z)}$) and of course $-1 \in \mathbb R^-$. That is due to the logarithm (or alternativaly the argument function) beeing impossible to define (as a holomorphic function) on the whole complex plain.

The problem is that the equation $x^{\pi} = 1$ doesn't really make sense if you don't specifiy what $x^{\pi}$ means. Non-integer powers are kind of tricky...